# How to log and view errors in Android Studio 3?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, android-monitor

I just upgraded to Android Studio 3.0.

After some changes to my app, I ran the application and got a crash on my phone. This was not unexpected, but when I opened the Android Profiler, which is supposed to replace the Android Monitor, I could not view any of the error messages that were available on the Android Monitor. Furthermore, there is no logging of what is happening like it used to do...how do I get this back?

How do I view these messages?

**Update:** I know logcat, but I am getting different messages on it than from the android monitor. Screenshot [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW0Fu.png). The screenshot shows that the phone is disconnected but it really isn't. I just took the picture when my phone wasn't connected.

Thanks

Comment: All the error messages and logging happens at the Logcat view. View > Tool Windows > Logcat

Comment: you can save your logs in file or SQLite for future use.

Comment: Basically, the former Android Monitor split into separate LogCat and Android Profiler tools. Which is good, because the Android Profiler [profiles even when you do not ask it to](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68850784).

Comment: i am aware that the logging happens in logcat, but logcat does not show all messages like it used to. before, when running the app, when a button clicked/some event executed, it showed up on logcat. now it doesn't. is this happening just for me or everyone?

Comment: @BLRBoy I just want to make sure, when you were testing it did it show [DISCONNECTED] next to the phone and app name? Sometimes you can have wrong device selected and not notice.

Comment: No its the right device...

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can see logs in `Logcat`

[image]